# Adding breakpoints programmatically using pdb in python

Tags: python, pdb

I find that in large multi-tier pieces of software it is typically easier to debug python code by putting the following within the code.

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` this sets a breakpoint at the LOC where I put the statement, and I can continue within the code using pdb in an interactive way and inspect the code execution etc.

I would like to know if its possible to add more than one breakpoints for such python debugging such that I can do `c` in the interactive python debugger and hit the next breakpoint?

i.e. for instance

```
<python code>
import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
... interactive debugging....
...press c here....
<more python code>
...
....
<breakpoint>// How can we insert such a breakpoint?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once did this for `ipdb` by heavily modifying it [here](https://github.com/VisionSystemsInc/vsi_common/blob/a60561483b4a616f5fb533332b6c22dc68a41b3f/python/vsi/tools/vdb_ipdb.py#L97-L132). However, I recently reinvented the wheel, in a way I think is simpler will work with any Bdb debugger. Tested on `pdb` and and `ipdb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pdb
import sys
import ipdb.__main__

def foo(x):
  return x+1

class RunningTrace():
  def set_running_trace(self):
    frame = sys._getframe().f_back
    self.botframe = None
    self.setup(frame, None)
    while frame:
      frame.f_trace = self.trace_dispatch
      self.botframe = frame
      frame = frame.f_back
    self.set_continue()
    self.quitting = False
    sys.settrace(self.trace_dispatch)

class ProgrammaticPdb(pdb.Pdb, RunningTrace):
  pass

class ProgrammaticIpdb(ipdb.__main__.debugger_cls, RunningTrace):
  pass

p = ProgrammaticPdb()
# p = ProgrammaticIpdb(ipdb.__main__.def_colors)

p.onecmd('b bar.py:38') # Works before set_running_trace
p.set_running_trace()
p.onecmd('b foo')       # only works after calling set_running_trace
p.onecmd('l')

x=-1
x=2
x=0
x=foo(x)

print(x)
```

You can set breakpoints by file/line number before calling `set_running_trace`, however you can only set breakpoints that depend on scope after calling `set_running_trace`, such as the function name `foo` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Following the @andy way, in more recent ipdb versions you can use:

```
debugger_cls = ipdb.__main__._get_debugger_cls()
```